# How to set more than one instrument by Python plus Mingus?

Tags: python, audio, mpmusicplayercontroller, fluidsynth

In the following example, A and B have the setados instruments, but both A and B using only the last object to be set, it is as if rewrite.

```
from mingus.midi import fluidsynth as a
from mingus.midi import fluidsynth as b
from mingus.containers import Note

a.init('/usr/share/sounds/sf2/FluidR3_GM.sf2',"alsa")
a.set_instrument(0, 34, 0)
b.set_instrument(0, 35, 0)

a.play_Note(26, 0, 127)
a.sleep(0.5)
b.play_Note(26, 0, 127)
b.sleep(0.5)
```

How can I set a tool for A and B to another instrument in the same script, or some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you write:

```
from mingus.midi import fluidsynth as a
from mingus.midi import fluidsynth as b
```

then `a` and `b` as the same identical object. So writing `b.set_instrument(0, 35, 0)` is the same as `a.set_instrument(0, 35, 0)`. As far as I understand `fluidsynth` you should use two different channels for each instruments:

```
a.set_instrument(0, 34)
a.set_instrument(1, 35)

a.play_Note(26, 0, 127)
a.sleep(0.5)
a.play_Note(26, 1, 127)
a.sleep(0.5)
```